# JS Enabled in A WebView

Tags: javascript, android-webview, mobile-application, penetration-testing

I'm testing a native mobile application and the scanner is pointing out the following problem:

**JS Enabled in A WebView**

Description:
The mobile application has enabled JavaScript in WebView. By default, JavaScript is disabled in WebView.
If enabled it can bring various JS-related security issues, such as cross-site scripting (xss) attacks.

Solution:
Disable Javascript in WebView.

Is the solution applicable? If so, how to fix and if not what should be done?

An image of the line of code that the scanner is showing the problem at:
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

> Is the solution applicable? If so, how to fix and if not what should be done?

Depends. There are cases where a webview needs to have JS enabled for some reason. So this might be intentional.
However, if an attacker is able to somehow control that webview, for example being able to define the URL of the webview it can be abused. In that case you would want more restrictions set on addition to disabling JS on the webview.